# SharePoint 2010 Parallel Approval Workflow should stop if any of the approvers reject the item

Tags: designer-workflow, approval-process

I am trying to build an approval workflow in SharePoint 2010 that will assign in parallel tasks to multiple approvers. All the approvers are expected to either approve or reject.I'm using "Assign approval Task" action in SPD 2010 workflow to achieve this.

By default, the workflow moves to the next step even if an approver rejects the item.But,I want all the approvers to provide their decision,but if atleast one approver rejects the item, the workflow should be stopped and should not proceed to next step.

I understand that If i want the workflow to stop on first rejection,I want to set the variable "CancelOnRejection" to Yes before the approval process is started. But in my case, I want all the approver's decision but if atleast one approver rejects the item, the workflow should be stopped.

How to achieve this?